# Show success message when gulp task is completed

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-babel

I created a simple Gulp task to check for changes in my ES6 files. I would like to transpile them and show an error message when something went wrong.

The error screen is being displayed. However, **I would like to show a different message when everything is successful.** I tried the `.on('end')` method but this method will also be called when there are some errors.

My current Gulpfile looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const pump = require('pump');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const DISTRIBUTION_PATH = 'public/theme/js/app';
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const clear = require('clear');

gulp.task('transpile', () =>
    gulp.watch('theme/js/**/*.js', () => {
        return gulp.src('theme/js/**/*.js')
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(babel({
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: [
                    'transform-object-rest-spread'
                ]
            }))
            .on('error', err => {
                clear();
                gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Compilation Error]'));
                gutil.log(err.fileName + ( err.loc ? `( ${err.loc.line}, ${err.loc.column} ): ` : ': '));
                gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('error Babel: ' + err.message + '\n'));
                gutil.log(err.codeFrame);
            })
            .pipe(gulp.dest(DISTRIBUTION_PATH));
    })
);
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msg

Comment: Thanks for our quick reply! I know that plugin but it only takes care of the message it self. I'm actually looking for an `on('success', () => console.log('Yay success!'))` callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer might be a bit late, but for the Googler like myself I've created a solution. I've added a boolean isSuccess to determine whether the transpilation was successful. If there is an error isSuccess becomes false and the message is not shown "on end."

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const pump = require('pump');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const DISTRIBUTION_PATH = 'public/theme/js/app';
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const clear = require('clear');

gulp.task('transpile', () =>
    gulp.watch('theme/js/**/*.js', () => {
        let isSuccess = true;
        return gulp.src('theme/js/**/*.js')
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(babel({
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: [
                    'transform-object-rest-spread'
                ]
            }))
            .on('error', err => {
                isSuccess = false;
                clear();
                gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Compilation Error]'));
                gutil.log(err.fileName + ( err.loc ? `( ${err.loc.line}, ${err.loc.column} ): ` : ': '));
                gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('error Babel: ' + err.message + '\n'));
                gutil.log(err.codeFrame);
            })
            .pipe(gulp.dest(DISTRIBUTION_PATH))
            .on('end', ()=> {
                if( isSuccess )
                    console.log('Yay success!');
            });
    })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
.on('error', () => {
   // some log or code for failure
 })
.on('end', () => {
   // some log or code for success
 });
```